# counting unique elements in lists

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe containing one column of lists.

```
names                                       unique_values
[B-PER,I-PER,I-PER,B-PER]                        2
[I-PER,N-PER,B-PER,I-PER,A-PER]                  4
[B-PER,A-PER,I-PER]                              3
[B-PER, A-PER,A-PER,A-PER]                       2
```

I have to count each distinct value in a column of lists and If value appears more than once count it as one. How can I achieve it

Thanks

Comment: Is `unique_values` the expected output?

Comment: yes it is the expected output

Comment: @Bilal was my answer helpful to you ? Or were there any issues implementing it ?

Comment: Yes it is very helpful. but in real data I have NAN's in lists which i don't want to count. How can i achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combine `explode` with `nunique`

```
df["unique_values"] = df.names.explode().groupby(level = 0).nunique()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the inbulit `set` data type to do this -

```
df['unique_values'] = df['names'].apply(lambda a : len(set(a)))
```

This works as sets do not allow any duplicate elements in their construction so when you convert a list to a set it strips all duplicate elements and all you need to do is get the length of the resultant set.

to ignore NaN values in a list you can do the following -

```
df['unique_values'] = df['names'].apply(lambda a : len([x for x in set(a) if str(x) != 'nan']))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df["unique_values"] = df.names.explode().groupby(level = 0).unique().str.len()
```

**Output**

```
df
                                 names  unique_values
0         [B-PER, I-PER, I-PER, B-PER]              2
1  [I-PER, N-PER, B-PER, I-PER, A-PER]              4
2                [B-PER, A-PER, I-PER]              3
3         [B-PER, A-PER, A-PER, A-PER]              2
```